# Text-based game - first OOP project

Tags: python, python-2.x, adventure-game

I'm learning Python as my first language and this is my first OOP project. What improvements can I make on my code for style, best practices, better logic, and to make it more efficient?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random


class Chest(object):

    possible_contents = ['Key', 'Horn', 'Brandy']

    def __init__(self):
        self.chest_inventory = Inventory()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.chest_inventory)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def add_contents(self):
        random_item = [random.choice(Chest.possible_contents)]
        self.chest_inventory.add_inven_contents(random_item)


class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = Inventory()

    def take(self, item):
        item_list = item.inventory_list
        self.inventory.add_inven_contents(item_list)
        print("You aquire {0}".format(item_list))
        item.empty()

class Inventory(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory_list = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.inventory_list)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.inventory_list)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def add_inven_contents(self, item):
        for each in item:
            self.inventory_list.extend([each])

    def empty(self):
        self.inventory_list = []


class Get_Choice(object):

    def __init__(self, room_info):
        self.info = room_info

    def receive_input(self):
        options = self.info.options
        choice = None
        bad_input_message = 0

        while choice not in xrange(1, (len(self.info.options) + 1)):
            if bad_input_message == 1:
                print("Incorrect input, try again.")
            for each in options:
                list_index = options.index(each) + 1
                print("{0}. {1}".format(list_index, each))
            choice = raw_input("Enter a number> ")
            bad_input_message = 1
            if choice.isdigit():
                choice = int(choice)
            else:
                pass

        return choice

class Room(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.optionchoice = Get_Choice(self)
        self.firstrun = 0

    def print_scene(self):
        if self.firstrun == 0:
            print(self.__str__())


class Entrance(Room):

  def __init__(self):
        super(Entrance, self).__init__()      
        self.entrance_chest = Chest()
        self.options = [
            "Climb the ladder",  
            "Go through door",
            "Check the chest",
            ]

  def __str__(self):
    self.firstrun = 1
    return (
        "After a day of travel, you find and abandoned outpost. "
        "You decide to spend the night there. "
        "You enter the output. "
        "You see another door, a ladder, and a chest."
        )

  def run(self):
    self.entrance_chest.add_contents()
    chest_inven = self.entrance_chest.chest_inventory
    while True:
        choosenoption = self.optionchoice.receive_input()
        if choosenoption == 1:
            chest_inven.empty()
            return 'ladder'
        elif choosenoption == 2:
            chest_inven.empty()
            print("You mysteriously find yourself back in the same room.")
            return 'entrance'
        elif choosenoption == 3:
            if chest_inven.inventory_list != []:
                player1.take(chest_inven)
            else:
                print("It is empty")


class LadderRoom(Room):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LadderRoom, self).__init__()
        self.options = [
            "Try to open door",
            "Go back down ladder",
            ]

    def __str__(self):
        self.firstrun = 1
        return (
            "You enter a small room "
            "and there is a large door with a keyhole"
            )

    def run(self):
        end_text = (
            "You open the door with the key you found. "
            "Inside is a pile of gold. You win!"
            )
        while True:
            choosenoption = self.optionchoice.receive_input()
            if choosenoption == 1:
                if 'Key' in player1.inventory:
                    print(end_text)
                    return 'end'
                else:
                    print("The door is locked, you can't get in.")
            elif choosenoption == 2:
                print("As expected, you find yourself back at the entrance.")
                return 'entrance'


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = 'entrance'
        self.room0 = Entrance()
        self.room1 = LadderRoom()

    def play(self):
        while self.status != 'end':
            if self.status == 'entrance':
                self.room0.print_scene()
                self.status = self.room0.run()
            elif self.status == 'ladder':
                self.room1.print_scene()
                self.status = self.room1.run()
        raise SystemExit

player1 = Player()
engine1 = Engine()
engine1.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the `class` for the Inventory simpler:

```
class Inventory(list):

    def __del__(self):
        pass # this avoids an Inventory gets deleted, is it really necessary?

    def add_inven_contents(self, items): # as you're adding multiple items, name it items 
        self.extend(items) # extend takes an iterable
```

If you don't mind calling `inventory.extend` instead of `inventory.add_inven_contents` you can drop this method

This will allow to call some [additional methods](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) on Inventory, which isn't a problem in my opinion

Comment: Nice! That simplifies things a lot! Thank you!